# RRC state of an android

Tags: android, network-programming, wireless

Is it possible to get Radio Resource Control (RRC) state from Android device programmatically, If any public API available or hidden API's can also work?

Answer (score 2):

As no body has replied this, so i am answering my own question for others in case someone else have the same doubt.

Technically the answer should be "No", Because the radio chip on an android device is vendor specific and communication to radio chip is done via RIL which is kept in HAL abstraction. that means Nobody except the device manufacturer knows about How RIL library is communicating through the radio. Generally communication through radio is done via AT Commands and vendors do not exposes the AT Commands for getting radio state.

Samsung is exception for this, i.e. Samsung devices with intel infenion chipsets exposes the radio state to user on dialing some secret code which can be easily found on internet.

Hope this will help others who are looking for the same question.

Comment: Which secret code? Do you have a link to the information about Samsung devices? It would be of great help.